# Happens before between threads and atomic variable

Tags: java, concurrency, atomic, volatile, java.util.concurrent

Suppose an AtomicInteger,`c`, is shared between two threads, thread1 and thread2. Thread1 sets (one time only) a volatile variable `t1` using `c.incrementAndGet()`. Thread2 sets (one time only) a volatile variable `t2` using `c.incrementAndGet()`. Once t1 and t2 are set they are not set again by any other thread. Suppose that after thread1 sets `t1`, it checks the value of `t2` and gets `null`. Is it guaranteed that `t2` is subsequently set to a higher value then `t1`? (and visa versa). In other words are the assert below always true? Is so why?

```
AtomicInteger c = new AtomicInteger();
volatile Integer t1=null;
volatile Integer t2=null;

//Thread1
t1=c.incrementAndGet();
if(t2 == null){
  assert t2==null || t2>t1;
}

//Thread2
t2=c.incrementAndGet();
if(t1==null){
  assert t1==null || t1>t2;
}
```

I believe the asserts are true for the following reason:  If t1 is assigned a value from incrementing c and t2 has not yet been assigned a value by incrementing c then when t2 is subsequently assigned a value by incrementing c, it must be greater then the value of t1.

Update: Since as per the correct answer below the asserts may not always hold, I have added a part 2 question: Check out [Happens before between threads and atomic variable Part 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53365250/4350148).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no guarantee. The following could happen:

- thread2: c.incrementAndGet (c is 1, and t2 is still null, but will be initialized with 1 later)
- thread1: c.incrementAndGet (c is 2, and t1 is still null, but will be initialized with 2 later)
- thread1: t1 = 2
- thread1: if (t2 == null): the condition is true. The if block is evaluated
- thread2: t2 = 1
- thread1: t2 == null: the condition is false, so the other operand of the `or` is evaluated
- thread1: t2 > t1: false since t2 is 1 and t1 is 2
- thread1: assert: fails

Comment: Wow, very tricky. Did not consider that incrementAndGet and the assignment are tow operations.

Comment: What if I use in thread2 the following: c.updateAndGet(x->{t2=x; if(t1==null){assert t1==null || t1>t2;}return x+1;})

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/53365250/4350148 for a continuation of this problem

Answer (score 1):

No, they will not always be true. There is no guarantee that thread 1 will run before thread 2, or that the operations won't interleave. If they run as:

1. thread 2 assigns `t2 = 1`
2. thread 2 does its `if` check, which evaluates to true
3. thread 1 assigns `t1 = 2`
4. thread 2 does its assert

... then at step 3, thread 2 will see `t1 != null` and `t2 > t1`.

Thread 1 can similarly fail.

(As JB Nizet mentions, even the operations I wrote above are actually comprised of multiple operations. That level of detail isn't strictly necessary for this question specifically, but it *is* a good habit to get into to really break things down into their individual operations, like the incrementAndGet vs the assignment it goes into. Experience will let you filter them out a bit when you want to show why something won't work, but to show that it *will* work, you really do need to consider each operation.)